# Access Query for specific values

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

```
Date        Name    Charge
1/15/2015   Alpha   3.39
2/15/2015   Alpha   3.39
2/15/2015   Beta    3.39
2/15/2015   Gamma   2
3/15/2015   Gamma   3
3/15/2015   Alpha   5
4/15/2015   Beta    3.39
```

How can unique Name records be obtained such that only records with exclusively 3.39 is resulted for the specified table. Expected result for above table is only record 'Beta'. Alpha would not be in results because it has value 5 for one month.

Similar query was done (below) for querying '0' charges but '3.39' is now being attempted:

```
SELECT Name FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Name HAVING SUM(Charge) = 0
```

Comment: The above is just a sample snippet of thousands of rows of records that I'm expecting to use. Unfortunately, there's likely room for error if AVG is used

Comment: I was running into long query times when applying the solutions to 40,000 records and also QA of query results showed that the floating number of 3.39 is causing inconsistent results. I'll now try this extra solution of using the temp table to reduce query time along with the Abs function.

Comment: The database doesn't allow to change the unit type to 'Currency' (strange) and also when QA'ing the new solution, it's currently off by ~4,000 records (greater)

Comment: Unfortunately these solutions have not given the correct results upon QA....is there another method available? I've hitten a wall with this issue

Answer (score 1):

I would first select the records that violate the condition (<> 3.39), then select all names that are not in that group.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
FROM tbl
WHERE [Name] NOT IN
    (SELECT [Name]
    FROM tbl
    WHERE Charge <> 3.39)
```

Note that calculating with floating point numbers can be tricky, you may need to do something like `WHERE Abs(Charge - 3.39) < 0.000001`.

`Name` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe#__toc272229040), so needs to be put in square brackets. Even better would be to avoid such field names.

---

**Edit**

With a large table, Access doesn't perform too well with NOT IN.

A solution should be to insert the subquery result into a "temp" table with a single column `sName`.

Query 1:

```
DELETE * FROM tTemp
```

Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO tTemp (sName)
SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
FROM tbl
WHERE Charge <> 3.39
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl.[Name]
FROM tbl LEFT JOIN tTemp ON tbl.[Name] = tTemp.sName
WHERE tTemp.sName IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would the query look like with that "WHERE Abs(Charge - 3.39) < 0.000001" line?

Comment: @stitch70: just put that instead of `WHERE Charge <> 3.39`

Comment: Unfortunately with over 40,000 records, this query takes over an hour to query. Would there be another method of doing this?

Comment: When looking at the temp table, it appears that Query 2 only yields blank fields in the temp table

Comment: It's okay I got that part, I used INTO instead of INSERT INTO

Comment: The database doesn't allow to change the unit type to 'Currency' (strange) and also when QA'ing the new solution, it's currently off by ~4,000 records (greater)

Comment: Unfortunately these solutions have not given the correct results upon QA....is there another method available? I've hitten a wall with this issue

Comment: I've went ahead and used: "SELECT Name FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Name HAVING AVG(Charge) = 3.39"